# Memory usage in Iterative-Deepening DFS(ID-DFS) and BFS

Tags: algorithm, search

I am reading a lecture in https://www.ics.uci.edu/~welling/teaching/271fall09/UninformedSearch271f09.pdf

The memory usage in BFS is O(b^d+1), and the memory usage in ID-DFS is O(bd).

There's one thing that I want to check, why ID-DFS does not store all the visited nodes?

The reason I have figure out is that it only needs to store the path and the nodes that it has expanded on the path. For other nodes outside the path that it has visited can be discarded from the tree(free them from memory), because these nodes are not benefit to directing from root to the goal node.

For BFS, because we don't know where the solution is, we can not discard the nodes that we have visited until we have found the solution.

Is above thought correct or wrong?

Notes:
To be more precise, in ID-DFS, to the best of my knowledge, when visiting a node, we should generate all legal children of it, say n children, and visit the first child n1. For the second child n2, it will be visited until the limited-depth DFS has done searching n1. That's why the memory usage in ID-DFS is O(bd), branching factor times depth. For some application that it don't need to generate all children when visiting a node, it can just generate the first child; for the second child, it can be generated after searching the n1 and return. For such modification, it only need to store the path, so its memory usage is O(d).

Comment: Yes except your meaning of "nodes waiting" to be searched by DFS is vague. The only cost of IDFS is storing some kind of iterator (e.g. an index into an array of child pointers) for each node in the path to the root.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I have modified some words to make it more comprehensive(I hope), and adding some notes to discuss the memory usage of it.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming this is an introudction to an AI course.

Let us first make sure we are talking about tree search instead of graph search. In tree search you just need a fringe while you will need both a fringe and a close set in graph search. The fringe will be a pripority queue in general to just store the node to be visited. For BFS and DFS respectively, it can be reduced to queue and stack respectively. For graph search, the close set will be used to store the nodes that all child nodes have been visited in order to prune unnecessary duplicated search.

Consider a search tree that each node has `b` child nodes and `m` tiers.

Time Complexity: DFS takes `O(b^m)` to find one solution while BFS takes `O(b^s)` to find one, where `s` is the depth of the shallowest solution.

Space Complexity: Here the space complexity refers to the largest size that fringe will ever consume. DFS only takes `O(bm)` since it only need to store the slibing nodes on the path to root, while BFS takes roughly the last tier, i.e. `O(b^s)`

Here are the illustration for DFS vs BFS:

[image][image]

We can easily see that in most case, it is faster to use BFS than DFS to find one solution, but DFS takes less memory than BFS. ID-DFS is, therefore, nothing but a combination of BFS and DFS. So to search up to depth d, the memory consumption is the same as DFS, namely `O(bd)`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, there's one more question: Why don't we need to store all the nodes generated in BFS? You inferred that "BFS takes O(b^s) ", while all generated nodes are 1+b+b^2+b^3+...b^s = O(b^(s+1)). I think we need to store all the nodes generated, then we can know how to go to the solution when found.

Comment: What do you mean by all generated nodes?

Comment: @user3148602 Here it assumes that the shallowest solution is at depth `s`. So the **largest** size of the fringe is `O(b^s)`, which is roughly the number of nodes in depth `s`. Any nodes above that have already been popped from the fringe earlier, so it does not contribute to the largest memory consumption.

Comment: @user3148602 If you are concern about the path to the solution. There are several aways to implement. One particular is to have a pointer pointing from child node to parent node. Then once you find the solution, you can easily track back to root using these pointers. Another way, which I believe is more generic, is to store `path` in the fringe instead of `node`.

Comment: We can think traveling sales man problem, each node represent a city, when you find a solution, you need to know to traverse the city, so the previous node you should store into memory. In BFS, you can not abandon the nodes that you have generated(expanded or visited) until you have visited the last city. Then you can know the path from the start to the end.

Comment: But we not only need to store the fringe but also the path, the pointer is a common implementation to the parent node, so there's indeed the parent is also in memory, which is the generated nodes that I mean.